# Put a viewpager in a popup window

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put a viewpager in a popup window. When My current code looks like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    viewPager = new ViewPager(this);

    layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2, -2);//wrap content

    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);

    //...

    popUp.setContentView(viewPager);

    mainLayout.addView(button);

    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });

    setContentView(mainLayout);

}//end of oncreate
```

But when I try to run it android throws a IllegalStateException error, saying that viewpager requires a viewID. How do I resolve this?

```
08-11 11:32:13.996 2300-2300/lii2.github.com.popupapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: lii2.github.com.popupapp, PID: 2300
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager with adapter lii2.github.com.popupapp.MainActivity$MyPagerAdapter@316fcff requires a view id
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.startUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:81)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1117)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your resources:

```
    <item name="viewpager" type="id" />
```

and call

```
    viewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
```

Comment: I tried this, however Android Studio is saying it "Cannot resolve Method setID(int)", even after cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Note that the "d" in "setId" is lowercase.