# Inflate ViewPagers with different ids

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I want dynamically add ViewPagers to Fragment. For example I created xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and inflate views with it. But ViewPagers shows incorrect. Look like problem related with same ids for ViewPagers. When I removed `android:id="@+id/vpUsers"` I got error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager with adapter com.raybytes.SMSAddict.adapters.UserSectionAdapter$MyFragmentPagerAdapter@11a219d0 requires a view id
```

Same problem if I create ViewPagers programatically because ids are requeired but manually setting of ids is dangerous.

How can I inflate or programatically create few ViewPagers with different ids? (number of ViewPagers is unknown)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution described here would work for your situation:
[Put a viewpager in a popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900704/put-a-viewpager-in-a-popup-window)
Basically, you have to add this to your resources:

```
<item name="viewpager" type="id" />
```

and call

```
viewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
```